# How to create my private key to sign my blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

Can you please tell me how can I create my private key to sign my blackberry application (java)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate your own keys, you have to request them from RIM: https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/